# Производительность Listview

Tags: android, listview, java, прокрутка

Здравствуйте!

Я хотел бы задать вопрос по поводу производительности Listview. У меня есть приложение, в котором присутсвует листвью. В нем содержится 700-800 элементов. 
При скроллинге приложение тормозит. Я прочитал про патерн Viewholder и реализовал его, чтобы улучшить производительность. Но, к сожалению, это не помогло. При прокрутке листвью также тормозило. Как с этим бороться? Скажем, у меня на телефоне стоит плеер, в котором тоже наверняка используется листвью, и в этом плеере у меня около тысячи песен, и список прокручивается без единого тормоза. Как подобное можно реализовать? К сожалению, код адаптера показать пока не могу (добавлю, если нужно, позже).

Разметка элемента листвью выглядит так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/artistText" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/titleText" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/durationText" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/synchedSongCaption"       
        android:id="@+id/synchedText" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:id="@+id/progressText" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/toDownloadSong"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/downloadProgress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:max="100"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />  
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/contextMenuButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />"
</LinearLayout>
```

UPD

вот здесь [код адаптера](http://pastebin.com/5v0EFqA0)

Comment: Сложно что-то сказать без кода адаптера =/

Comment: @Suvitruf добавил кое-что. Правда, всего кода сейчас под рукой нет. Может, по этому сможете что-то подсказать?

Comment: На первый взгляд вроде всё правильно.

Comment: но вот скроллится медленно. Я удалил из разметки все контролы, кроме titleText, artistText и  durationText. Стало вроде быстрее, но рывки при скролле остались. Неужели производитльеность там такая плохая, что возникают проблемы при скролле элементов, содержащих всего десяток контролов?

Comment: на первый взгляд все правильно, единственное, что вызывает вопросы:   
 
    Audio song = getModel(position);
    
может, этот метод медленно работает?

Comment: @metalurgus  нет там все в порядке. Это всего лишь вот что

    protected T getModel(int position) {
      return ((T) getItem(position));
    }

Comment: я бы закешировал вызовы `FormatHelper.secondsToTimeStringFormat` и `StringHelper.reduceText` прямо внутрь модели. То есть, при вызове проверяем, если ли в специальном поле форматированное значение. Если нет, получаем его. Потом выводим.

Главное, корректно обрабатывать ситуацию, когда эти поля обновляются.

Comment: м-да, видимо, придется засекать время выполнения... когда-то давно пользовался тулзой для таких целей, вроде бы встроена в Device Monitor

Comment: попробуйте уменьшить кол-во вьюх, например, объединить 5 textView в одну. получать данные через cursor. Может, телефон слабый?

Comment: @gcoder телефон не слабый. Xperia Z. Не топ, конечно, но железо нормальное. 
Объединить контролы - попробую. Но вообще странно, что он не может нормально работать с таким не большим числом контролов.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте поменять **ListView** на **RecyclerView**. Он совместим со старыми API. Там, как говорит гугол всё быстрее работает.

Ну или подгружать элементы в список по мере прокрутки. Одним из множества [endless scrolling ListView](http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/)

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего основные тормоза находятся в куске:

```
 Audio song = getModel(position);
```

Советую реализовать примерно следующую штуку:

1. Песенки кэшировать/складывать в БД SQLitе
2. Над SQLite организовать чтение через `CursorLoader`
3. А собственно выдергивание песенок (`Audio`) из `Cursor` вынести в `AsyncTask`

В результате будет следующее - загрузка списка будет мгновенное, далее по ходу отработки `AsyncTask`а из SQLite `ListView` будет потихоньку один за одним показывать ваши песенки: имя артиста, название и проч. инфу.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ я уже писал в комментариях - в методе getModel проблемы нет. Это всего лишь обертка над getItem и возвращает уже готовые данные

Comment: @JuniorTwo кхм... ну-ну песенки тягаются из сети и не тормозит? :)

Comment: Нет дело не в этом. Песенки загружаются отдельно при запуске приложения и во время жизни приложения висят в памяти (там только инфо о песнях, а не сами mp3шки). То есть данные, используемые в листвью, уже заранее подготовлены.